# Selection script for maya

Tags: animation, selection, maya, mel

I'm noob in script but good in animation, I need some help to create a script selection.

I found an exemple :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Get selected objects

curSel = maya.cmds.ls(sl=True)

# Or, you can also specify a type in the listRelatives command

nurbsNodes = maya.cmds.listRelatives(curSel, allDescendents=True, noIntermediate=True, fullPath=True, type="nurbsCurve", path=True)
cmds.select(nurbsNodes)
```

But It doesn't select all the character's controlers...

I would like If I select a character controler curve or locator and I run the script, the result is all controls who can be keyed should be selected. Without the referenced character name.

Thanks a lot for the one who can help

Answer (score 0):

Currently the listRelatives command is being used to list all child nodes under the currently selected transforms, whose type is a NURBS Curve, e.g. `type="nurbsCurve"`. Typically all nodes in Maya *inherit* from some other node type *(It's worth checking the nodes in Maya help -> technical documents ->nodes)*. Luckily locator nodes and curves both inherit from 'geometryShape', so you should be able to replace "nurbsCurve" with "geometryShape", and that will probably get you most of the way there. You *may* need to ignore certain returned nodes though - i.e. polygonal meshes you are using for rendering.